# How to make the screen flash, not working

Tags: javascript

```
var flashStep = 1;
function flash() {
 if(flashStep==1) {
 document.bgColor="FFFF00";
 flashStep=2;
 }
 else {
 document.bgColor="FF0000";
 flashStep=1;
 }
}
var task = window.setInterval("flash()",1000);
```

This code is supposed to make the screen flash, but does not work at all. http://jsfiddle.net/phjnM/2/. Why does this not work, it looks flawless to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the (global) scope being applied when you pass a string to `setInterval`. If you pass a function reference instead it works:

var task = window.setInterval(flash,1000);

See http://jsfiddle.net/phjnM/7/

The other option is in jsfiddle choose the "nowrap" option so that your code isn't defined in an onload/onready handler's scope...

Answer (score 7):

Several issues. First of all, `bgColor` is a property of elements - it doesn't apply to `document`. Perhaps you meant `document.body`? Second, you're *using* `bgColor`. Please don't. You should instead use `style.backgroundColor`. Third, you'll probably want to use a boolean value for two states. Fourth, never pass a string to `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. So, your code, rewritten, would be something along the lines of:

```
var flash = false;
var task = setInterval(function() {
    if(flash = !flash) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is a good summary of things that should be changed, but you didn't actually explain why the code from the OP doesn't work, i.e., in a general sense although it's not actually _wrong_ to pass a string to `setInterval` it will affect the scope and thus won't work if the flash function is defined inside an onload/onready handler. `document.bgColor` does work (at least in some browsers).

Comment: @nnnnnn: It works - but it's still horrible. Kind of like IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Because your code in the JSFiddle is wrapped in an onload function.

[image]

Passing a reference to the function will fix it.

```
var task = window.setInterval(flash,1000);
```

Or an alternative would be to choose a `(no wrap)` option from the menu on the left.

---

By the way, do this to color the document background.

```
var i = 0;
var task = setInterval(flash, 1000);

function flash() {
    document.documentElement.style.backgroundColor=(i = ~i) ? '#ff0' : '#f00';
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phjnM/10/)**

Comment: @minitech: How so? [Solution 1](http://jsfiddle.net/NCCRp/), [Solution 2](http://jsfiddle.net/NCCRp/1/)

Comment: Yes, okay, you said to pass the reference. How about bgColor? It's BGCOLOR for goodness' sakes!!! I'll remove the downvote though, I just have this reflexive reaction to BGCOLOR!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
document.bgColor="FFFF00"
```

you need this form:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="#FFFF00";
```

You were missing the `.body.style.`, you had the wrong name for the style attribute `backgroundColor` and you need to have a `#` on the color value.

Further, your setTimeout() should be like this:

```
var task = setInterval(flash,1000);
```

In your fiddle, you can get the flash function to be global, by changing it's definition to:

```
window.flash = function() {
```

You can see this all work in a revised version of your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/h4VZm/

Comment: `bgColor` works, old-school. (At least it works in the particular browser I happened to test with.) But yes, setting `style.backgroundColor` is a better plan.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.setInterval(flash, 1000)`.

This particular problem was probably a scope problem when running the code on jsfiddle. In general, don't pass code as string when you actually want to pass a callback, which in Javascript you can do by passing the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(flash,1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/phjnM/5/

Answer (score 0):

See now its working,
http://jsfiddle.net/phjnM/8/

Comment: Why did you use jQuery, yet not use jQuery? If you're going to use jQuery, use it all the way. Don't use a half-baked solution.

Comment: @minitech: Clearly Jayantha is borrowing the ready callback to make explicit what jsFiddle conceals. Why is this a problem for you? Enough with the half-baked comments.

Comment: @RightSaidFred I won't argue. This isn't a good answer. It doesn't explain anything. It can be improved.

Comment: @minitech: **That has nothing to do with your original comment.** *"Why did you use jQuery, yet not use jQuery? If you're going to use jQuery, use it all the way. Don't use a half-baked solution."*

Comment: @RightSaidFred: It actually does. If someone is going to rewrite the code without explaining anything, it should be rewritten *all the way*, especially when modified to use a library that wasn't included in the first place and isn't even included in jsFiddle by default. Then explained. But this is a minor fix that doesn't explain what the changes were, what the issue was, and doesn't even include the code in its body.

Comment: @minitech: I don't disagree that the code should be explained (and included in directly in the answer). I do disagree that your initial comment had anything to do with the lack of an explanation. You're trying to make it seems as though I'm arguing something that I'm not... and you're failing.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Well, *I* get the feeling you're trying to find some sort of problem with every single one of my comments because you're annoyed that I didn't find your answer complete. So please, stop the pointless arguing.

Comment: @minitech: It isn't pointless. My answer was complete and correct, but you incorrectly commented on and down voted it. Then I saw you left an irrelevant comment on this answer, so I took issue with it. So it has to do entirely with your misplaced criticisms of other people's answers. Your comments with respect to the content of the actual answer are valid. If that's what you meant, that's what you should have said.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Your answer was correct, and I apologize for the downvote. It's definitely neither complete nor deserving of an upvote, however (that is, in my humble opinion). You ignored `bgColor` (until this next edit, which I didn't see, and which is also wrong - `~0` is `0` so that will stay stuck at one color) and you didn't actually explain what the problem was, you just said that it was "because it's wrapped in onLoad." So? The actual *reason*? Now please, if you agree that this answer isn't complete, kindly stop bothering me.

Comment: @minitech: `~0 === -1; // true` and `~-1 === 0; // true`. `-1` is truthy, so it alternates. If you don't want me to address your comments that are directed at me, then don't continue the dialog. And in my comment above, I said that your comments with respect to the content of the actual answer (meaning what was posted here) are valid. Though that part was added as an edit, so you may have missed it.